# Creating a RIA using Django & SmartClient

Tags: django, extjs, ria, smartclient

I am investigating the possibility of implementing a RIA involving lots of grid-based views (think Excel) using a combination of Django or Rails, and SmartClient (smartclient.com) or ExtJS.

Has anyone successfully done either and can someone provide some links to written or audiovisual material on this? I am looking or tutorials etc, specifically for SmartClient? There is plenty of material on ExtJS, little on SmartClient as far as I can tell.

Right now I am leaning towards SmartClient and Django. SmartClient because at first glance it seems more complete than ExtJS (though less extensively documented).

I have read through the SmartClient "Getting started" document, but I am looking for some more in-depth material.

Edit: I was expecting someone to vote for closing this as a matter of principle. I think it is a useful question if it gets a useful answer. I am not asking for a discussion on ExtJS vs. SmartClient or Rails vs. Django. Just looking for pointers to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

We're doing very similar project right now. And we decided to go with ExtJs as a front end. I can send you screenshots or even show you live demo if you'd like.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear in my question. I am looking more for material like tutorials / How tos. I know some ExtJS frontends, we have one with a different backend approach. I'll clarify my question. Are you happy with the approach?

Comment: Yes. We've happy. It took some time to tie together ExtJs and RIA Services on the back end, but we're pretty satisfied with results so far.

Comment: Sencha has some Guides for ExtJs MVC approach - very helpful from my viewpoint.